# I need to get the values that have a specific result on .value_counts()

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, linear-algebra

I want to get the values that have a specific result on .value_counts(), eg:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9]) 
ser = pd.Series(data) 
counts_nums = ser.value_counts()
print(counts_nums)
```

Here are the results:

```
7    3
9    2
3    2
6    1
5    1
dtype: int64
```

Now, I want to find a way to get the values have a count number equal to 2, which are 9 and 3. In other words, I want to index .value_counts()

What are the different ways of doing this?

Comment: Try `counts_nums[counts_nums == 2]` to get 9 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get a list.

```
count_values[count_values == 2].index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[9, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
counts_nums.loc[counts_nums==2]
```